# ImportError: cannot import name 'Checkpoint' from 'ray.air'

Tags: python, ray

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/hyperparameter_tuning_tutorial.html) to tune hyperparameters in PyTorch using Ray, copy-pasted everything but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Checkpoint' from 'ray.air'
```

from this line of import:

```py
from ray.air import Checkpoint
```

I installed ray using `pip install -U "ray[tune]"` as suggested on the official website. After getting the error, to be sure, I also tried a more general `pip install ray`, which did not fix anything.
I have version `ray==2.9.0` installed.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install older version `2.7.0`:

```
pip install ray[tune]==2.7.0
```

### Update :

For the newest version the Ray AIR session is replaced with a Ray Train context object.
You can import  `Checkpoint` using :

```py
from ray.train import Checkpoint
```

You need to adjust your code as follow:

```py
from ray import air, train

# Ray Train methods and classes:
air.session.report               -> train.report
air.session.get_dataset_shard    -> train.get_dataset_shard
air.session.get_checkpoint       -> train.get_checkpoint
air.Checkpoint                   -> train.Checkpoint
air.Result                       -> train.Result

# Ray Train configurations:
air.config.CheckpointConfig      -> train.CheckpointConfig
air.config.FailureConfig         -> train.FailureConfig
air.config.RunConfig             -> train.RunConfig
air.config.ScalingConfig         -> train.ScalingConfig

# Ray TrainContext methods:
air.session.get_experiment_name  -> train.get_context().get_experiment_name
air.session.get_trial_name       -> train.get_context().get_trial_name
air.session.get_trial_id         -> train.get_context().get_trial_id
air.session.get_trial_resources  -> train.get_context().get_trial_resources
air.session.get_trial_dir        -> train.get_context().get_trial_dir
air.session.get_world_size       -> train.get_context().get_world_size
air.session.get_world_rank       -> train.get_context().get_world_rank
air.session.get_local_rank       -> train.get_context().get_local_rank
air.session.get_local_world_size -> train.get_context().get_local_world_size
air.session.get_node_rank        -> train.get_context().get_node_rank
```

For more informations see :

- [Refining the Ray AIR Surface API](https://github.com/ray-project/enhancements/pull/36)
- [2.7 Migration Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J-09US8cXc-tpl2A1BpOrlHLTEDMdIJp6Ah1ifBUw7Y/view)